# how to recover solr shard

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am new to solr.
My solr version is 5.2.1

There are multimple collections and each collections has multiple year wise shards.
Each shard contains 2/3 replicas.

Every collection is working fine, but in one collection only one shard is showing down.

```
"test2020":{
            "range":null,
            "state":"active",
            "replicas":{
              "core_node12":{
                "state":"recovering",
                "core":"test_index_testid124_test2020_replica1",
                "node_name":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8983_solr",
                "base_url":"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8983/solr"},
              "core_node21":{
                "state":"recovering",
                "core":"test_index_testid124_test2020_replica1",
                "node_name":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8983_solr",
                "base_url":"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8983/solr"},
              "core_node32":{
                "state":"down",
                "core":"test_index_testid124_test2020_replica1",
                "node_name":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8983_solr",
                "base_url":"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8983/solr",
                "leader":"true"}}},
```

Since 2 days, it is showing recovering / down.
I tried,

> reloading shard
>
> reloading core
>
> restart solr / zookeeper

in solr logs, it is showing below info

**INFO  - 2020-04-27 05:28:41.776; [   ] org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler; In WaitForState(recovering): collection=test_index_testid124, shard=test2020, thisCore=test_index_testid124_test2020_replica1, leaderDoesNotNeedRecovery=false, isLeader? true, live=true, checkLive=true, currentState=recovering, localState=down, nodeName=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8983_solr, coreNodeName=core_node12, onlyIfActiveCheckResult=true, nodeProps: core_node12:{"state":"recovering","core":"test_index_testid124_test2020_replica1","node_name":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8983_solr","base_url":"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8983/solr"}**

Please help me to resolve this issue

Thanks in Advance